# What is the difference between onPresentScreen and onLeaveApplication?

Tags: android, admob

In the Admob SDK, there exists an interface called AdListener, documented below.

```
public interface AdListener {
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad);
  public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, AdRequest.ErrorCode error);
  public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad);
  public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad);
  public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad);
}
```

I'm trying to do something if the user clicks on an ad. I believe there are two fields which occur if a user clicks on an ad, namely the `onPresentScreen()` and `onLeaveApplication()`. Is this correct, and is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onLeaveApplication()` gets fired when the ad is causing the device to switch to a different application, such as a web browser when the ad is clicked.

`onPresentScreen()` gets fired when the ad renders something that is full screen.

In the likely case of the ad rendering a web browser or market, both of these callbacks get fired after clicking the ad.  But theoretically, clicking the ad could render a new activity within your application, in which case `onPresentScreen()` gets fired but `onLeaveApplication()` does not.

The above corner case may be particular for those using [DoubleClick for Publishers](http://www.google.com/doubleclick/publishers/mobile.html) and have more control over the ad inventory they serve - a live AdMob ad wouldn't load a new activity within your application.